# Use np.where extract item occurring error index out of range

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I want to extract an item from two columns use np.where, DataFrame like:
(total 100,000+ lines)

add Description: the "eNBID" is not always the third part of "ID" , the data is crazy dirty.

```py
       ID         eNBID
460-00-2354-9     2354
4600023549        2354
46001368511       6789
4600332783112     32783
```

the result I want is:

```
       ID         eNBID     CI
460-00-2354-9     2354       9
4600023549        2354       9
46001368511       6789       11
4600332783112     32783      112
```

my code is :

```py
df['Ci'] = np.where(df['ID'].astype(str).str.contains(r'-',na=False,regex=True), \
           df['ID'].apply(lambda x:re.split('-',str(x))[-1], \
           df.apply(lambda x:re.findall('([\w]{5})'+'([\w]{%d}'%(len(str(x.eNBID)))+'(\w*)',str(x.ID))[0][-1], axis=1))
```

the error is:

```py
IndexError:('list index out of range','occurred at index 0')
```

there is my new code:

```py
cond = df['ID'].astype(str).str.contains('-',na=False,regex=True)
df['CI'] = np.where(cond,df['ID'].apply(lambda x:re.split('-',str(x))[-1]), \
          df[~cond].apply(lambda x:re.findall('([\w]{5})'+'([\w]{%d}'%(len(str(x.eNBID)))+'(\w*)',str(x.ID))[0][-1], axis=1)) if len(str(x.eNBID))<(len(str(x.ID))-5) else "null", axis=1))
```

the error is :

```py
ValueError:operands could not be broadcast together with shapes(100883,)(100883,)(78,)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Erfan I have assumed that the CI are the numbers found in the ID right after the eNBID (at least this is consistent with the example provided)

Comment: sorry,it is my fault，I didn't say very clearly,the "eNBID" is not always the third part of "ID" , the data is crazy dirty, only the length of "eNBID" can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df['s']=df['ID'].replace('-','', regex=True)
df['Ci'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['s'][(5+len(str(x.eNBID))):], axis=1)
df.drop('s', axis=1, inplace = True)
```

**Output**

```
     ID            eNBID    Ci
0   460-00-2354-9   2354    9
1   4600023549      2354    9
2   46001368511     6789    11
3   4600332783112   32783   112
```

Comment: Thank you very much , because the data is crazy dirty, the "eNBID" is not always the third part of "ID" , so your code only work under certain conditions

Comment: Can you update your data to represent all scenarios? We can work only with the data you provide. In my solution, it does not matter where „eNBID“ is. I am using  eNBID to split ID and then taking the portion after it.

Comment: sorry,it's my fault, and I can figure out your code,I have updated my data demo just now.

Comment: What is the logic for 3rd row? I cannot figure it. 6789 is not part of ID at all.

Comment: the dirty data has no logic, only the length of "eNBID" can be used.

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged in `R`, here is a solution:

```
data$CI = sapply(1:nrow(data),function(x){
  gsub(paste0(".*",data$eNBID[x],"-?"),"",data$ID[x])
})

             ID eNBID  CI
1 460-00-2354-9  2354   9
2    4600023549  2354   9
3   46001368511 36851   1
4 4600332783112 32783 112
```

We remove all characters up until the `eNBID`, as well as (optionally) the `-`character.

**data**

```
data = read.table(textConnection(" 
460-00-2354-9     2354
                                 4600023549        2354
                                 46001368511       36851
                                 4600332783112     32783"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(data)=c("ID","eNBID")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there with your logic using `re` and `np.where`:

```
import re

df['CI'] = np.where(df['ID'].str.contains('-'),
                    df.apply(lambda x: re.findall(f'(?<={x.eNBID}\-)(\d+)', x['ID']), axis=1),
                    df.apply(lambda x: re.findall(f'(?<={x.eNBID})(\d+)', x['ID']), axis=1))

df['CI'] = df['CI'].str.join('')
```

**Output**

```
              ID  eNBID   CI
0  460-00-2354-9   2354    9
1     4600023549   2354    9
2    46001368511  36851    1
3  4600332783112  32783  112
```

Comment: Great, dont forget to [vote/accept as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this helped you :)